# How to use module functions in Python classes

Tags: python

I've googled a bunch and can't seem to figure out how to actually do this:

Given I have a general purpose utility method like so:

```
def __square(n):
    return n*n
```

Then I have some class where I might like to use this method internally:

```
def __square(n):
    return n*n

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = 2

    def bar(self):
        return self.baz + __square(self.baz)
```

Well, that doesn't work. I get `NameError '_Foo__square' is not defined`

Why?

As a workaround I've ended up doing things like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = 2

    def bar(self):
        return baz + self.square(self.baz)

    def square(self,n):
        return n*n
```

But that feels silly to me because the square function has nothing to do with a Foo instance, nor would I expect or want it to be a method on Foo instances.

What's the "pythonic" way of dealing with this sort of thing?

**EDIT**

I figured out at least one part of this: I was getting this behavior because I think of these utility methods as private, and I've been naming them like `def __square(n):`.

I didn't realize that was special, and when typing the example above I initially didn't type it that way. I've now edited the question to reflect how it was actually typed.

So now my question is: why does putting `__` in front of a top level method break it, or seem to? I understood that to be the convention for naming "private things" in Python, since it doesn't work in this case what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Where is `square` defined in the relative file structure?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. The former snippets work just as well for me both in 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: I've been getting this when I have the functions defined in the same file, a few lines apart. Using Python 3.5

Comment: Can you post the full code of the .py file?

Comment: @hege_hegedus I tried copy/pasting this and you're right. Now I realize the issue is when I use names like `__square`. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Andrew now that's an interesting question, let me dig into the docs

Comment: Would've been nice if you'd told us the actual name of the function to begin with. :P

Comment: @kojiro my real code is a lot hairier than this, copying it verbatim would have just cluttered the question. I typed up an accurate representation of my question to the best of my knowledge, and when I realized the problem in my question (thus revealing the answer), I immediately updated the question. For future visitors to SO, reading my question, seeing the discovery process revealed by the edits, and reading jsbueno's excellent answer, should be very educational. For that reason I disagree with you, I don't think "it would have been nice" if I had presented the question any differently.

Comment: Just to mention it here: when I first read the question, the correct function name was already updated. I'd be able to guess the problem if the error message was fully quoted as it is (name error on _Foo__square), though.

Comment: @Andrew you're right that it does require specialized Python knowledge to realize the significance of underscores at the beginning of a name, and thus you would've had no reason to suspect that changing the name of the function would explain this problem. But I still think having simplified the code you were asking about, it _would have been nice_ if you had tested the alteration. And maybe that's something meta you can take away from this question in addition to the direct knowledge of Python under unders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not prefix your function name with two underscores  - `__`  - the Python compiler performs a name mangling operation whenever a name prefixed by two underscores name is found in code inside a class. - Threfore your reference to `__square` is transformed in a reference to the non-existing `_Foo_square` at compile (to bytecode) time.

Just use a single `_` like in `_square` and you won't have this error.

Python has no such a thing like "private" names. By convention - and convention only - a function or attribute prefixed with `_` should not be called or accessed from code from other scopes.

Some write ups out there on the internet, in an effort to create equivalence for every concept existing in other wide-known OOP languages, actually mention that a double-underscore prefix is equivalent to "private" variables in those languages. That is a common mistake in older documentation - more recent articles avoid this fault.

The behavior a double-underscore prefix has is something different - which sometimes can serve the same purpose as `private` (as opposed to `protected`) attributes have: it does transform the variable name in an operation known as "name mangling" throughout Python's documentation. Usually this is used for an attribute name, and it is transformed into a name that is unique to the container class, in a way it will be accessible, by default, only on the class it was defined, not on its subclasses. The transformation is deterministic and well documented: one underscore and the class name is prepended to the attribute's name (two underscores included). Therefore, a `Polygon` class that would have an `__area` attribute would actually have a `_Polygon__area` at run time - and if a derived `class Square(Polygon):`  class would try to access an `__area` attribute in its code, it would actually access `_Square__area` at run time. (But it would be possible to read and write the superclass' `__area` by explicitly writing `Square._Polygon__area` in the code)

Comment: Today I learned something new about python again. It is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references